# Join on multiple table

Tags: mysql

I have 5 tables like below

```
user
id     name      
11     rajesh
12     kumar

group 
id     name
21     sales
22     dev

domain
id     name    
51     network        
52     database

user_group
user_id     group_id    
11          21        

user_domain
user_id     domain_id    
12          51
```

I need to retrive all users who are member of atleast one group or domain. Here is the query that I am using to join two tables.

```
select user.name from user join user_domain on user.id=user_domain.user_id
```

I am able to join tables user and group. But along with that I need to join user and domain also. When I try like below I am getting zero results.

```
select user.name from user 
left join user_group on user.id=user_group.user_id 
join user_domain on user.id=user_domain.user_id
```

If I change to left join like below I am getting all users.

```
select user.name from user 
left join user_group on user.id=group.user_id 
left join user_domain on user.id=user_domain.user_id
```

Please advise

Comment: Post you SQL where 'some tasks are missing'. Maybe it only needs some tweaking.

Comment: suggestion: remove form the question the tables that are not relevant to it: group, product - don't seem relevant

Comment: @ElzoValugi Removed table word

Comment: this is even more confusing, I do not understand which are the tables and which are the columns. better give us the create statement for the tables in question

Comment: Try in this way for productid `select userid, taskid, productid from task_product 
 INNER JOIN task ON task.taskid = task_product.taskid
    INNER JOIN product ON product.productid = task_product.productid
    INNER JOIN product ON product.productid = task_product.productid` or If you can make sqlfiddle then would be better

Comment: @PiyushGupta, why not just give it as answer instead of commenting it?

Comment: I am updating the question. Give me a moment

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, That is only guess I'm not sure.....Once he will update question with dumy data then will update.

Comment: I do not know why always people giving down voting. Is this the portal just for techie people to discuss. Not for novice?

Comment: You should explain more clearly what you want: in your queries you are joining `user` and `group`, but the `id`s do not match among them. Maybe you want to join `user` with `user_group`? Same thing for `user` and `user_domain`. Once you select the right users from both tables, you can just use `UNION` to get the complete set.

Comment: @Cynical you are right. Corrected the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this enough?

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `user` JOIN `user_group` ON `user`.`id` = `user_group`.`user_id`
UNION
SELECT `id`
FROM `user` JOIN `user_domain` ON `user`.`id` = `user_domain`.`user_id`;
```